# Asked benefit to prevent injury, HR wants to see the injury first. How to get around it?

Tags: human-resources

I travel a lot. I am a big person, and I don't fit in normal economy seats. I use extra legroom or I don't fly.
In my past job I used to fly with Premium Economy all the time.
In my brand new job, I can't choose my seats anymore.

Last time I was on a 10 hours flight with such narrow seats that it was impossible for me to sit normally, I had to keep my torso turned towards the corridor the whole time. After take off a hostess moved me to an empty row with extra legroom and I managed.
Now I asked an exception to HR. My GP filled a form stating that as a big person I cannot fit in a normal economy seat, as it would cause intense back pain.

HR rejected the explanation, stating that I need to provide a valid medical condition. If I fly in normal seats, I will have intense pain in legs and back, I won't be able to sleep on the flight and I won't be able to perform my job immediately after I land, which is the main reason they fly me around.

How can I make HR help prevent a medical condition, when they want to see one first?

Comment: What country/state ?

Comment: If this condition is not a disability (definition depends on country), but rules OP from doing his job (part of which is flying) then this may lead to trouble as company may not have to adjust for this specific condition and may decide to handle it differently when pressed. Did you disclose this during the hiring process?

Comment: @thursdaysgeek, Thanks, I just noticed that a couple of seconds after I posted my comment. I deleted that question.

Comment: What country is this? Can you refuse to fly?

Comment: Please expand the acronym "GP" as originally I didn't read that as "general physician: (I guess?). Initially I thought I thought it was like your internal boss ("producer" is common IME), so I didn't understand the situation at all.

Comment: @DanielR.Collins: GP is an old and well know abbreviation for General Practitioner.  In the US most insurance companies require you to get one, using that term, for non-emergency and non-specialist treatment, or pay extra for doctors visits. You also frequently can’t see a specialist unless the GP has referred you to one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds as if your HR are working from a script designed for dealing with *accommodations for disability*. It may be helpful to nudge them onto a *risk management* script.

[UK health and safety rules](https://www.hse.gov.uk/simple-health-safety/risk/index.htm) - many other countries have similar legislation:

> As an employer, you’re required by law to protect your employees, and
>   others, from harm.
>
> Under the Management of Health and Safety at Work Regulations 1999,
>   the minimum you must do is:
>
> - identify what could cause injury or illness in your business (hazards)
> - decide how likely it is that someone could be harmed and how seriously (the risk)
> - take action to eliminate the hazard, or if this isn’t possible, control the risk

With that in mind, you might ask your doctor to rewrite the letter in a way that matches the language of those rules, e.g.:

> In my professional opinion, requiring Mr. Monoandale to fly in standard economy seats presents a **high risk** of **serious musculoskeletal injury**. This hazard should be eliminated by providing [whatever kind of seat works for you] whenever he is required to fly for work.

If your work has a separate Health and Safety office, you should copy them in on this, since risk prevention is their priority and they may be able to help talk sense into HR.

Framed like this, it should be easier to make it clear to them that they have a legal responsibility here.

Comment: It's worth reading a bit further into the h&s rules as it suggests redesigning the job as a solution to an identified risk, and that is absolutely one of the roads they can take. And that would mean taking OP from the flying crew altogether. I also have serious doubts that a GP has the knowledge to reliably asses, without a shadow of a doubt, that it's economy seats that cause OPs condition, and not any other factor.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Yeah, redesign is a possibility, but AFAIK that would apply with disability too - if they'd rather send somebody else than pay the extra, not much that can be done about that. And "shadow of a doubt" probably isn't the standard that applies here.

Comment: That's why I proposed just talking your way into a better ticket instead of throwing down with her, much higher chance of success :)

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul Not sure about that "higher chance of success" - many workplaces have policies that require travel to be taken on the cheapest practical fare or similar, in which case the boss would be obliged to say no. At that point you're back to the formal options, with the added problem that the boss has already said no once and may be suspicious of a medically-based request.

Comment: Nothing suspicious in wanting to solve this by talking first, rather than going into doctors notes. It doesn't make the health concerns and less valid. Why didn't op brought this up earlier before the trip is the most suspicious part in this all.

Answer (score 10):

If I understand correctly, an accredited medical professional certifies that you can't fly regular economy and require specific accommodation. In many countries this creates a legal obligation for the company to provide this accommodation.

Provided your country falls into this category, it would be highly unusual for HR to reject a GPs statement. I would try again and ask HR what specific documentation they require and I would also consult with a local employment lawyer what your rights/options are. At the same time read up on your employee handbook and study your employer's policies. The rules of this type of thing is typically spelled out fairly detailed in the HR policies.

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes the UK as location (based on user profile).

> Now I asked an exception to HR.

Not a first step I would recommend.

Instead, I would shoot a message to my boss: "Hey X, those cramped seats on the economy are really uncomfortable, got a bit of back-ache now, can we maybe spring for the premium economy next time around? It's only 20 quid more, and a lifesaver for me. Thanks!". And that usually gets the job done with very limited friction. This door is likely still open for you.

Probably when the trip was planned was the best time to broach the subject and avoid the unpleasant flight altogether.

But as we don't have a time machine:

> My GP filled a form stating that as a big person I cannot fit in a
>   normal economy seat, as it would cause intense back pain.

I am not sure what form are we talking about here, but as you decided to go for such exemption on medical disability grounds, you must fall under the protection of the Equality Act 2010. To get there, it's a process, and as you did not present HR with disability diagnosis after being hired, or now, I assume you have not gone through it yet.

Following assumes that the condition in question is obesity based on the language used by OP. Please let me know if that's not accurate and ignore the next paragraph.

While it's a path you should consider exploring, as it stands obesity in the UK is not qualified as a disability, and as per ECJ ruling from 2014. Conditions that may develop from it certainly can classify, like Diabetes, but obesity itself does not. So if that is the case, you may likely not have a realistic shot to qualify, more so as you say yourself that you do not have a back condition yet.

Putting it further on the line with HR may backfire, and as it is, you are not protected under the Equality Act 2010, so tread carefully. And try to just have an honest conversation, find a middle ground towards the more expensive flying ticket, rather than going through the paperwork.

If you cannot do that, maybe seek a career that doesn't involve flying. Your health should come first, and any adjustments offered must be reasonable from both sides, which also means that if flying makes you uncomfortable, you should probably avoid doing it (this is a simplification to make a point across that the burden is on both sides, not just the employer).

Or if all the employer offers you is the standard economy (despite all the negotiations), then pay for the premium option out of your own pocket, which while far from ideal, is certainly better than suffering for a few hours each way. Health first!

Comment: I would not assume that the OPs condition is obesity.  I'm 6'1" and not obese and have to choose my seats carefully when flying.  Depending on the airline, in standard economy my knees can hit the seat in front of me.  A person only slightly taller than me could conceivably have genuine issues with posture that would cause all sorts of pains depending on the length of the flight.

Comment: @PeterM At 6’3” I agree with you - stuck in a normal seat I wedged the back of the seat in front... person in front complained seat did not work. Air hostess could not do much! But being assumed obese is poor.

Comment: While I am not short / midget, I am not tall either. And the economy plane seats are usually uncomfortable, not providing enough leg space. So I can only imagine the pain for longer-legged persons.

Comment: @PeterM We all know that economy seats suck, that's hardly the op issue here. And if it's just being tall (although the language used by OP suggests not) then the answer applies as much here.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul  The only physical description that the OP gives about themselves is that they are "a big person".  The word "Big" has many connotations, or which "Obese" may be only one of them.  But by describing the OP as obese you are making an assumption about which of these connotations the OP is applying to themselves.  The OP also expresses that they "use extra legroom" which IMHO also goes against describing the OP as obese, as obesity has nothing to do with height